# Is there .NET Support for the nwCreate API?

Tags: autodesk-navisworks

I'm trying to use the NWCreate tool to create model geometry, but the only examples are in c++.  Is there a .NET wrapper available for the NWCreate API?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry not available, please check [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/navisworks-api/use-nwcreate-api-in-c-net/td-p/5062520).